# Nginx - Redirect HTTP to HTTPS not working

Tags: docker, nginx

I've tried a few different examples online. It seems like no matter what I do, I get a "this site can't be reached" when I type in http://example.com or http://www.example.com.

I must have something misconfigured somewhere. Https is working just fine.

```
user nginx;

events {
    worker_connections 1000;
}
http {
    upstream web-api {
        server web:80;
    }

    server {
          listen         80;
          server_name    *.example.com;
          return         301 https://$server_name$request_uri;
    } 


    server {
        listen 443 ssl;
        server_name www.example.com;
        ssl_certificate /etc/nginx/certs/www_example_com.crt;
        ssl_certificate_key /etc/nginx/certs/example.key;
        location / {
            proxy_pass http://web-api;
                proxy_set_header   Upgrade $http_upgrade;
                proxy_set_header   Connection keep-alive;
                proxy_set_header   Host $host;
                proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;
                proxy_set_header   X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
                proxy_set_header   X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
    }
  }
}
```

```
version: '3.7'
services:
        web:
                image: 'exampleimage'
                container_name: 'examplecontainer'
                ports:
                        - '5000:80'
                restart: always
        reverseproxy:
                image: nginx:alpine
                volumes:
                        - ./data/certs:/etc/nginx/certs
                        - ./nginx.conf:/etc/nginx/nginx.conf:ro
                ports:
                        - '80:80'
                        - '443:443'  
                depends_on:
                        - web
                restart: always
```

Comment: Try `$host` instead of `$server_name`, as the latter is the value of the `server_name` directive.